# Set Icon on app and different icon on the taskbar of the app

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, taskbar

I have set the Icon in the forms properties and it displays. And the same icon displays on the taskbar when the app is launched. I want a different icon to show in the taskbar and not the same one that is on the app. I tried setting the icon up in Project properties under Resources - Icon and manifest but the taskbar icon still doesn't change. How do i change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icon setup in the Project Properties -> Application -> resources - can only change the icon of the EXE file.

[image]

Comment: I saw that now. So where do i go to, to change the Icon that is shown on the taskbar?

Comment: @SMG you need to change the icon of the form itself. Assign the icon to the form that you have assigned in project properties.

Comment: so my form and task bar icon has to be the same? It cant be different